# Using isomorphic-style-loader with nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, isomorphic-style-loader

I'm new to **nextjs** and was trying to a way to modularize my CSS. Found this solution and tried to implement this [Example app with isomorphic-style-loader](https://github.com/timmywil/next.js/tree/e06a09c4d795e94e011e77128b8c47725165020e/examples/with-isomorphic-style-loader) on my local.

The problem is the CSS is not getting applied. The CSS Module classes are getting applied `.App-root-2UbkX` for `.root` class in the css file. But the CSS is not applied to it.

It is creating an empty `style` tag.

[image: Screenshot]

I'm using the latest version of node and npm.

Comment: Did you wrap your page with [pageWithStyles](https://github.com/timmywil/next.js/blob/e06a09c4d795e94e011e77128b8c47725165020e/examples/with-isomorphic-style-loader/pageWithStyles.js) HOC ?

Comment: @Faris Yes I have followed all the instructions in that example. Also with the `pageWithStyles` it is creating a `style` tag but it is empty.